# Pyspark takeOrdered by key

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a rdd and can´t  sort my results from my second `key(Number)`

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(' user3 ', 24),
 (' user1 ', 38),
 (' dhg ', 22),
 (' user2 ', 5),
 (' root ', 28),
 (' fido ', 1)])

rdd.takeOrdered(5)
```

Which returns

```
[(' dhg ', 22), (' fido ', 1), (' root ', 28), (' user1 ', 38), (' user2 ', 5)]
```

My desired result is:

```
[('user1', 38), ('root', 28), ('dhg', 22), ('user2', 5), ('fido', 1)]
```

I mean, ordered by number and descending.

PS: *These values were obtained using `reduceByKey` to count elements*

Any clue on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a custom ordering function to `takeOrdered` like this:

```
values = rdd.takeOrdered(5, lambda x: -x[1])

print(values)
#[(' user1 ', 38), (' root ', 28), (' user3 ', 24), (' dhg ', 22), (' user2 ', 5)]
```